# PHP str_split and UTF8 polish characters

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm having problem with spliting word with utf-8 polish chars.

I've been checking php docs for str_split, but there's no parameter to set charset.

I've word: **"mała"**
And i have to split it by letters to wrap each single letter with **span** and return html string in result.

Result of str_split('mała'):

```
array:5 [
  0 => "m"
  1 => "a"
  2 => b"Å"
  3 => b"‚"
  4 => "a"
]
```

json_last_error_message() returns **"Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"** error, so as i thought it's problem related to polish letters, but i can't find a way to set str_split charset.

Here's prepared array to be JSON encoded:

```
array:2 [
  "pieces" => array:6 [
    0 => "<span class="dropable">m</span><span class="dropable">a</span><span class="dropable">m</span><span class="dropable">a</span>"
    1 => "<span class="dropable">m</span><span class="dropable">a</span><span class="dropable">s</span><span class="dropable">a</span>"
    2 => "<span class="dropable">m</span><span class="dropable">a</span><span class="dropable">p</span><span class="dropable">a</span>"
    3 => b"<span class="dropable">m</span><span class="dropable">a</span><span class="dropable">Å</span><span class="dropable">‚</span><span class="dropable">a</span>"
    4 => "<span class="dropable">m</span><span class="dropable">a</span><span class="dropable">c</span><span class="dropable">a</span>"
    5 => "<span class="dropable">m</span><span class="dropable">a</span><span class="dropable">t</span><span class="dropable">a</span>"
  ]
  "engine" => "Wstepne"
]
```

Index number 3 contains weird "b" before string and these malformed characters.

Code to generate these strings is:

```
$htmlString = '';
foreach(str_split($piece) as $key => $letter){ 
    $htmlString .= '<span class="dropable">'.$letter.'</span>';
}
return $htmlString;
```

Tried to use utf8_encode on $letter, it fixed problem with b in front of string, but still it creates 2 spans:

```
3 => "<span class="dropable">m</span><span class="dropable">a</span><span class="dropable">Å</span><span class="dropable">‚</span><span class="dropable">a</span>"
```

Any more ideas?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`str_split` works on byte level and not on character level (despite its name). So in fact you're splitting `mała` along its bytes and not along its characters. That's why you're getting an array of five items instead of four. Index 2 and 3 together form the UTF-8 encoding of `ł`.

You need to use either the `mbstring` or the `iconv` extension to split your string manually.

```
$str = 'mała';
$len = mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8');
$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $result[] = mb_substr($str, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I woudln't say "byte level", more like the assumption that 1 char = 1 byte, because PHP's core string fucntions aren't unicode-aware.

Comment: That's true - if you know that the terms *char* and *byte* are equivalent and that unicode characters are something different. Otherwise it might be confusing. That's why I chose *byte*.

Comment: You could also use the `grapheme_*` functions from the intl-extension that will then also behave correctly on combined Unicode-characters… ;)

Comment: I used this to count the unique letters of various words. `$letters = []; foreach ($words as $word) { $len = mb_strlen($word, 'UTF-8'); for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) { $letters[] = mb_substr($word, $i, 1, 'UTF-8'); } }  $letters = array_unique($letters); asort($letters);
$letters_string = implode(' ', $letters); echo $letters_string;`